# Problem with the position of SyntaxHighlighter Evolved javascript

Tags: plugin-syntaxhighlighter

Hello i use SyntaxHighlighter Evolved (http://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/description) and it's load their script after

`</html>`

tag. i want to put the script of this plugin before the

`</html>`

tag in pages.

you can see this issue online here. http://rokesh.ir/tutorial-adding-sharing-buttons-on-social-networks-to-wordpress-contents

Comment: where is the `wp_footer` function located in your theme?

Comment: Show us the content of your theme’s `footer.php`.

Comment: It's located before `</body></html>` tags

Comment: I use SyntaxHighlighter Evolved on a few sites, and have not seen this behaviour. It must be something specific to your website.

Comment: What are you think about this problem?